# Codeigniter query return Null on remote MySQL Server

Tags: php, codeigniter, null

i'm using Codeigniter to developt web application. Usually apache and mysql server hosting on same server. Today i have to seperate them.

```
10.10.10.1 - apache
10.10.10.2 - mysql
```

These two can pinging each other right now. Here is my my.cnf file on mysql server.

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
bind-address=10.10.10.2
old_passwords=0
```

i'm binding mysql server to 10.10.10.2 ip adress. Because of these two server have a 2 diffirent interface.

After that, i created a user on mysql server with that query.

```
GRANT ALL ON appdb.* TO appuser@'10.10.10.2' identified by 'passw0rd';
```

For test i write that little php script and run on apache server which is have 10.10.10.1 ip adress..

```
<?php
$username = "appuser";
$password = "passw0rd";
$hostname = "10.10.10.2"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("appdb",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select examples");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT @@version");

print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result));

mysql_close($dbhandle);

?>
```

everythings fine! Result coming back to me. i start tcpdump on mysql server and i saw response tcp stream.

here is my codeigniter database.php file

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '10.10.10.2';
$db['default']['port']     = '3306';
$db['default']['username'] = 'appuser';
$db['default']['password'] = 'passw0rd';
$db['default']['database'] = 'appdb';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

to be sure everythings are okey on controller and models file. i wrote test method in controller.

```
 public function test()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("select @@version");

        print_r($query->result());
    }
```

and output on browser

```
Array ( )
```

i start tcpdump -vvv -i eth1 on mysql server to be sure any tcp connection is coming to db server ? and i'm sure there is no tcp connection opened when i call test function on browser. Shortly; CI do not connect MySQL server. and i cant figure out why ?

Any idea ?

Thank you guys.

PS : First $db['default']['db_debug'] is TRUE. When i get the page on browser while db_debug defined as TRUE i m getting that error. i changed to FALSE for fix that problem. But i'm sure there is no problem with db_debug while i'm using locahost as a mysql server. When i changed it to remote server that error came through.

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

Comment: hi just try by giving localhost in db host name

Answer (score 0):

you should also `GRANT ALL ON appdb.* TO appuser@'10.10.10.1' identified by 'passw0rd';` while your app runs on ip `10.10.10.1`

Comment: Yes my app server runs in 10.10.10.1 and also I have no local dns server so I cant use fdqn instead of ip address. But I tried to add /etc/hosts file mydbdomain as 10.10.10.2 and changed codeigniter config. Still same.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed problem. If you r using centos 6.x or another RHEL version of linux as a application server. Than you should know, selinux came enabled as a default. When I tried to connect db server my little php script and execute it on command line as a root privileges, there was no problem. But your application runs www-data or something else which is dont have root privileges. So while selnix enabled, other users can not open tcp socket. That was a reason why CI queries returns null. If you disable selinux, problem fixed.